# Selenium, wait for element, page object model, c# bindings

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-webdriver

How can we wait for a IWebElement to be (re)attached to DOM? My scenario goes like so, that i select one value from dropdown1 and after click databinding occurs on dropdown2. So when my test goes like select "foo" from Dd1, then select "bar" from Dd2 -> i will get an exception, there is a race condition as the Dd2 has not been rendered yet.
Now, i know, that we have the WebDriverWait class, and we could use the Until method smth like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(By.Id("foo"));
```

But i really wouldn't like to bring the locator string ("foo") to my test logic, as it seems to be defeating the point of using page object models. When using a Page object model I already have the IWebElement instance

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_actionButtonBarControl_btnSave")]
    public IWebElement BtnSave { get; set; }
```

So, do you know any ways to implicitly wait for IWebElement to be ready for communication?

Comment: So at the moment i use it as follows, but still looking for good solution

Comment: internal static void WaitForElementToBeReadyAndSelectByText(IWebElement webElement, string s)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var element = new SelectElement(webElement);
                    element.SelectByText(s);
                    break;
                }
                catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(200);  
                }
            }
        }

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this? I am struggling with the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Hi I know its a bit late but I had this same issue and I got round it by doing the following (using your code):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
wait.Until(By.Id(_pageModel.BtnSave.GetAttribute("id"));
```

Its then just returning the value of the ID attribute and stops you having to pollute your test code with element lookups. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `locator values` mean you can go for Implicit Wait instead of using the Explicit Wait. The Implicit wait too make the `driver` instance to wait for given period of time.

`Actual difference to Explicit Wait is that it will tell Web driver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.The default setting is 0.`

**Code:**

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

One thing to keep in mind is that once the implicit wait is set - it will remain for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

For more info use this link    http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html#implicitlyWait(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Answer (score 0):

What we do is pass in a raw selector text like in `seleniumRC css=a, xpath=b`.

We then have a `findElement` method that will parse the request, get the appropriate `By` and search for the element